# QTWebKit or WebKit On AIX

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

I know that QtWebKit or WebKit is not supported n AIX.  But has anyone tried getting a smaller subset of the functionality for this compiled and working on AIX. I tried but somehow there is a file FastMalloc.h that does not compile there for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Right so I got this working for the old QtWebKit anyway. I had to comment out the platform specific code. I also forced FastMalloc to use the System Malloc. Also, to be noted that malloc(0) behaves differently in AIX. This is solved using FAST_MALLOC_MATCH_VALIDATION_FLAG but if you face problems I suggest changing fastMalloc to use malloc(1) when there is malloc(0).